# How do I add a label to a fill layer using Mapbox?

Tags: labeling, style, mapbox, json

I have a layer of jurisdictions, and am trying to label them at a certain extent (about 1:750000) but I can't get labels to show up at all. I've got the following code:

```
  "layerStyle": [
                {
                    "type": "fill",
                    "layout": {
                        "text-size": 10,
                        "text-field": [
                            "get",
                            "NAME"
                        ],
                        "text-variable-anchor": [
                            "top",
                            "bottom",
                            "left",
                            "right"
                        ],
                        "text-radial-offset": 0.5,
                        "text-font": [
                            "Open Sans Regular"
                        ],
                        "text-justify": "auto",
                        "text-optional": true
                    },
                    "paint": {
                        "fill-color": "hsl(101, 83%, 61%)",
                        "fill-opacity":  [
                            "interpolate",
                            [
                                "linear"
                            ],
                            [
                                "zoom"
                            ],
                            0,
                            0.5,
                            22,
                            0.5
                        ],
                        "fill-outline-color": "#000000"
                    }
                }
            ],
```

Comment: Try `"text-optional": false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create your labeled marker

```
   el = document.createElement("div");
   el.innerHTML = `Your desired html here`;
   el.className =`marker`;
   new mapboxgl.Marker(el);
```